# ls Ordering[Ordering[list]] optimal?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sorting, permutation

Given a list `list` with unique elements, the task is to replace each element by its position in `Sort[list]`. For example,

```
list = {"A", "B", "D", "C", "Z", "W"};
Position[Sort[list], #][[1, 1]] & /@ list
```

> {1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5}

Much more efficient is to call `Ordering` twice:

```
Ordering[Ordering[list]]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5}

When applied on a permutation of `Range[length]` this operation does nothing:

```
list = {2, 10, 1, 4, 8, 6, 3, 9, 5, 7};
Ordering[Ordering[list]]
```

> {2, 10, 1, 4, 8, 6, 3, 9, 5, 7}

Question: is there a more efficient way of doing this operation, making a single function call instead of calling `Ordering` twice?

---

## benchmarks

Solutions are given from fastest to slowest:

```
L = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7];

(* J.M.'s undocumented InversePermutation usage *)
R0 = InversePermutation[Ordering[L]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.39154 *)

(* Henrik Schumacher *)
R1[[Ordering[L]]] = R1 = Range[Length[L]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 2.42264 *)

(* original post *)
R2 = Ordering[Ordering[L]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 4.20186 *)

(* J.M. *)
R3 = PermutationList[InversePermutation[FindPermutation[L]]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 4.74717 *)

(* check *)
R0 == R1 == R2 == R3
(* True *)
```

Comment: Have you tried out `PermutationList[FindPermutation[list]]` or `InversePermutation[Ordering[list]]`?

Comment: Thanks @J.M.. I think that your use of `InversePermutation` on a permutation list instead of a permutation is undocumented. It's the fastest solution though. How do you know about all these undocumented tricks?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No,  `Ordering[Ordering[list]]` not optimal. And yes, there is a faster method:

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000000];

First@RepeatedTiming[
  a[[Ordering[list]]] = a = Range[Length[list]];
  ]

First@RepeatedTiming[
  b = Ordering[Ordering[list]]
  ]

a == b
```

> 0.13
>
> 0.236
>
> True

## Edit

J.M.'s second suggestion is more concise and at least as fast if not slightly faster:

```
c = InversePermutation[Ordering[list]]; // RepeatedTiming // First

c == b
```

> 0.124
>
> True

Comment: This solution cuts the effort down from two function calls to one function call plus one indexed substitution (very fast). 90% of what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, I hadn't even checked J.M.'s second solution because I expected (according to the documentation) that `InversePermutation` spits out a permutation, not a permutation list. But that's not the case when you feed it a permutation list.