# Optimization of function taking a permutation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, permutation

I have a function $f$ which takes a permutation $P$ of the integers 1-100 in order to give a numerical value $f(x)$. The function is given by a black box, but is relatively "smooth", so should be amenable to optimization.

For instance, define a function $f$:

```
f[samp_?ListQ] := Total@Total@Table[Table[(-1)^(i), {i, 1, Length[samp]}]
    * Reverse@Cos[Mod[samp, n]]* Mod[samp, n], {n, {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23}}]
```

Now `f[RandomSample[Range[100]]]` will give a numerical value, but I can't figure out how to specify this as an optimization problem only on $P$. I can't cast it into the form of the Travelling Salesman Problem, as the function depends on $x$ more generally than pairwise interactions.

Edit
I mentioned in a comment that what I'm actually trying to do is find the best-scoring set of words in a line of Scrabble tiles [as detailed in this puzzle](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/whats-your-best-scrabble-string/). For this, this is the code for scoring a permutation (without the blanks):

```
nonblanks = 
  Sort@ToLowerCase@StringSplit[
     "eeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaiiiiiiiiioooooooonnnnnnrrrrrrttttttllllssssuuuuddddgggbbccmmppffhhvvwwyykjxqz", ""];

dictionary = Import["https://norvig.com/ngrams/enable1.txt", "List"];
dictionaryMax = Max[StringLength /@ dictionary];

pointSub = Thread[CharacterRange["a", "z"] -> {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 8, 5, 
                      1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10}];
score[wordlist_?ListQ] := Total[Flatten@Characters@wordlist /. pointSub];

getScore[samp_?ListQ, scoreOnly_: False] := getScore[samp, scoreOnly] = 
     Module[{perm, poswords, wordlist},
      perm = nonblanks[[samp]];
      poswords = Flatten[Table[StringJoin@perm[[i ;; j]], {i, 1, (Length@perm) - 1}, 
                        {j, i + 1, Min[(Length@perm), i + dictionaryMax]}]];
    wordlist = Intersection[poswords, dictionary];
    If[scoreOnly, score@wordlist, {StringJoin@perm, score@wordlist, wordlist}]
 ]
```

So given any permutation of hte integers 1-98, getScore will give a numerical value:

```
getScore[Range[98]]
(* 158 *)
```

and you can see the words by:

```
getScore[Range[98], False]
{"rqciorwlstrndziimdfnsobtroaanikhijxieeevgesiwtpenuoustaearavhnfcdyoa\
glareiuumaploindteeaoeleetogyb", 158, {"aa", "ae", "ag", "aglare", 
  "an", "ani", "ar", "are", "ear", "el", "en", "es", "et", "glare", 
  "hi", "in", "khi", "la", "lar", "lee", "leet", "lo", "loin", "ma", 
  "map", "nu", "oe", "or", "oust", "pe", "pen", "re", "rei", "si", 
  "so", "sob", "ta", "tae", "tee", "to", "tog", "um", "us", "xi", "yo"}}
```

Comment: I show some approaches for this in notes [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260165600_Differential_Evolution_in_Discrete_and_Combinatorial_Optimization_Mathematica_tutorial_notes), in particular the sections "Relative position indexing" for permutations"  and "Representing and using permutations as shuffles", and "Another shuffle method".

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need?  There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. But wait! It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Comment: Should not the call to getScore above include a random permutation such as getScore[RandomSample[Range[98],False]?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about a [Monte-Carlo-Metropolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) search? I'll implement a simplistic version here. See complete universal code further down. **Update:** Cleaned-up code now [available in the Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaximizeOverPermutations), so you can use `ResourceFunction["MaximizeOverPermutations"]` instead of a locally-defined `MaximizeOverPermutations`. NUG25 and NUG30 are given as applications in the documentation.

To move stochastically through permutation space, we need a random-move generator. Here I'll only use random two-permutations on `M=100` list elements: given a list `L` of 100 elements, generate a new list that has two random elements interchanged,

```
M = 100;
randomperm[L_] := Permute[L, Cycles[{RandomSample[Range[M], 2]}]]
```

With this `randomperm` function we then travel stochastically through permutation-space using the [Metropolis-Hastings algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm). One step of this algorithm consists of proposing a step (with `randomperm`) and accepting/rejecting it depending on how much the merit function `f` increases/decreases:

```
f[samp_?ListQ] := f[samp] =     (* merit function with memoization *)
  Total@Total@Table[Table[(-1)^(i), {i, 1, Length[samp]}]*
    Reverse@Cos[Mod[samp, n]]*
    Mod[samp, n], {n, {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23}}]

MH[L_, β_] := Module[{L1, f0, f1, fdiff, prob},
  L1 = randomperm[L];   (* proposed new position *)
  f0 = f[L];            (* merit function of old position *)
  f1 = f[L1];           (* merit function of proposed new position *)
  fdiff = N[f1 - f0];   (* probability of accepting the move *)
  prob = If[fdiff > 0, 1, E^(β*fdiff)];  (* this is Metropolis-Hastings *)
  (* make the move? with calculated probability *)
  If[RandomReal[] <= prob, L1, L]]
```

The parameter `β` is an effective temperature that nobody knows how to set.

Let's experiment: start with the uniform permutation `Range[M]` and try with `β=1` to see how high we can go with `f`:

```
With[{β = 1, nstep = 30000},
  Z = NestList[MH[#, β] &, Range[M], nstep];]
ZZ = {#, f[#]} & /@ Z;
ListPlot[ZZ[[All, 2]]]
```

[image]

After only $30\,000$ Metropolis-Hastings steps we have already found a permutation that gives $f=1766.64$:

```
MaximalBy[ZZ, N@*Last] // DeleteDuplicates
(* {{{69, 31, 91, 2, 47, 89, 75, 37, 96, 61, 40, 22, 64, 95, 81,
      10, 66, 43, 19, 82, 85, 26, 28, 62, 78, 72, 34, 54, 45, 86,
      57, 60, 65, 33, 13, 74, 5, 8, 11, 68, 77, 88, 23, 15, 35,
      50, 83, 3, 93, 9, 18, 53, 63, 4, 58, 56, 30, 42, 46, 55, 36,
      94, 1, 87, 51, 44, 14, 21, 97, 27, 52, 49, 99, 73, 39, 71,
      7, 20, 41, 48, 24, 38, 29, 84, 6, 79, 90, 16, 59, 32, 12,
      70, 98, 67, 92, 100, 76, 25, 17, 80},
      184 + 154 Cos[1] - 157 Cos[2] - 252 Cos[3] - 194 Cos[4] + 
      69 Cos[5] + 238 Cos[6] + 190 Cos[7] + 8 Cos[8] - 154 Cos[9] - 
      120 Cos[10] + 17 Cos[11] + 94 Cos[12] + 134 Cos[13] + 19 Cos[14] - 
      81 Cos[15] - 76 Cos[16] + 14 Cos[17] + 23 Cos[18] + 36 Cos[19] + 
      4 Cos[20] - 35 Cos[21] - 21 Cos[22]}} *)
```

We can continue along this line with (i) increasing $\beta$, and (ii) introducing more moves, apart from `randomperm`.

For example, we can raise $\beta$ slowly during the MH-Iteration, starting with $\beta_{\text{min}}$ and going up to $\beta_{\text{max}}$: this gives a [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) advantage and tends to give higher results for `f`.

```
With[{βmin = 10^-2, βmax = 10, nstep = 10^6},
  With[{γ = N[(βmax/βmin)^(1/nstep)]},
    Z = NestList[{MH[#[[1]], #[[2]]], γ*#[[2]]} &, {Range[M], βmin}, nstep];]]
ZZ = {#[[1]], #[[2]], f[#[[1]]]} & /@ Z;
ListLogLinearPlot[ZZ[[All, {2, 3}]]]
```

[image]

After playing around for a while, all `f`-values computed so far are stored as `DownValues` of `f` and we can easily determine the absolutely largest `f`-value seen so far: in my case, the largest value ever seen was $f=1805.05$,

```
MaximalBy[Cases[DownValues[f], 
  RuleDelayed[_[f[L_ /; VectorQ[L, NumericQ]]], g_] :> {L, g}], 
  N@*Last]
(* {{{93, 61, 1, 15, 7, 2, 51, 72, 92, 78, 59, 43, 58, 10, 63, 21, 13, 
      48, 76, 49, 99, 42, 35, 31, 11, 95, 69, 88, 82, 36, 57, 77, 97, 73,
      47, 9, 28, 86, 24, 79, 6, 71, 39, 27, 83, 68, 40, 33, 98, 80, 75, 
      37, 91, 32, 19, 3, 56, 25, 84, 87, 41, 100, 52, 20, 64, 67, 34, 60,
      14, 50, 70, 16, 46, 17, 90, 94, 5, 55, 23, 54, 45, 4, 85, 38, 65, 
      26, 18, 44, 29, 22, 81, 89, 66, 74, 96, 62, 30, 8, 12, 53}, 
      170 + 174 Cos[1] - 150 Cos[2] - 282 Cos[3] - 172 Cos[4] + 
      120 Cos[5] + 218 Cos[6] + 191 Cos[7] - 13 Cos[8] - 214 Cos[9] - 
      141 Cos[10] + 22 Cos[11] + 117 Cos[12] + 109 Cos[13] + 
      27 Cos[14] - 60 Cos[15] - 52 Cos[16] + 6 Cos[17] + 23 Cos[18] + 
      43 Cos[19] - 8 Cos[20] - 29 Cos[21] - 19 Cos[22]}} *)

%[[All, 2]] // N
(* {1805.05} *)
```

## Complete and universal code for permutational optimization

Here is a version of the above code that is more cleaned up and emits useful error messages:

```
(* error messages *)
MaximizeOverPermutations::Pstart = "Starting permutation `1` is invalid.";
MaximizeOverPermutations::f = "Optimization function does not yield a real number on `1`.";

(* interface for calculation at fixed β *)
MaximizeOverPermutations[f_,                        (* function to optimize *)
                         M_Integer /; M >= 2,       (* number of arguments of f *)
                         β_?NumericQ,               (* annealing parameter *)
                         steps_Integer?Positive,    (* number of iteration steps *)
                         Pstart_: Automatic] :=     (* starting permutation *)
    MaximizeOverPermutations[f, M, {β, β}, steps, Pstart]

(* interface for calculation with geometrically ramping β *)
MaximizeOverPermutations[f_,                        (* function to optimize *)
                         M_Integer /; M >= 2,       (* number of arguments of f *)
                         {βstart_?NumericQ,         (* annealing parameter at start *)
                          βend_?NumericQ},          (* annealing parameter at end *)
                         steps_Integer?Positive,    (* number of iteration steps *)
                         Pstart_: Automatic] :=     (* starting permutation *)
Module[{P, g, Pmax, gmax, Pnew, gnew, β, γ, prob},
  (* determine the starting permutation *)
  P = Which[Pstart === Automatic, Range[M], 
            VectorQ[Pstart, IntegerQ] && Sort[Pstart] == Range[M], Pstart,
            True, Message[MaximizeOverPermutations::Pstart, Pstart]; $Failed];
  If[FailureQ[P], Return[$Failed]];
  (* evaluate the function on the starting permutation *)
  g = f[P] // N;
  If[! Element[g, Reals], Message[MaximizeOverPermutations::f, P]; Return[$Failed]];
  (* store maximum merit function *)
  Pmax = P; gmax = g;
  (* inverse temperature: geometric progression from βstart to βend *)
  β = βstart // N;
  γ = (βend/βstart)^(1/(steps - 1)) // N;
  (* Metropolis-Hastings iteration *)
  Do[
    (* propose a new permutation by applying a random 2-cycle *)
    Pnew = Permute[P, Cycles[{RandomSample[Range[M], 2]}]];
    (* evaluate the function on the new permutation *)
    gnew = f[Pnew] // N;
    If[! Element[gnew, Reals], 
      Message[MaximizeOverPermutations::f, Pnew]; Return[$Failed]];
    (* Metropolis-Hasting acceptance probability *)
    prob = If[gnew > g, 1, Quiet[Exp[-β (g - gnew)], General::munfl]];
    (* acceptance/rejection of the new permutation *)
    If[RandomReal[] <= prob,
      P = Pnew; g = gnew;
      If[g > gmax, Pmax = P; gmax = g]];
    (* update inverse temperature *)
    β *= γ,
  {steps}];
  (* return maximum found *)
  {Pmax, gmax}]
```

The OP's problem can be optimized with

```
f[samp_List] := Total[Table[(-1)^Range[Length[samp]]*Reverse@Cos[Mod[samp, n]]*
  Mod[samp, n], {n, {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23}}], 2]
MaximizeOverPermutations[f, 100, {1/100, 10}, 10^6]
```

A simpler problem, where we know the perfect optimum, is

```
SeedRandom[1234];
MM = 100;
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], MM];
Z[L_List] := L.x
```

The optimum is known: put the permutation in the [same order as the numbers in the list `x`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194094). For this particular case of random numbers, we get

```
Z[Ordering[Ordering[x]]]
(*    2625.98    *)
```

A quick search yields something not quite as high,

```
MaximizeOverPermutations[Z, MM, 1, 10^4][[2]]
(*    2597.67    *)
```

To track the progress of the Monte-Carlo search, use a [`Sow`/`Reap` combination](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html):

```
zz = Reap[MaximizeOverPermutations[Sow@*Z, MM, 1, 10^4]];
ListPlot[zz[[2, 1]], GridLines -> {None, {zz[[1, 2]]}}]
```

[image]

```
zz = Reap[MaximizeOverPermutations[Sow@*Z, MM, {1/10, 10}, 10^5]];
ListPlot[zz[[2, 1]], GridLines -> {None, {zz[[1, 2]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, and it deserves more upvotes (mine was the second such). You should consider submitting this to the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/) as a general optimization code for permutation problems. Inputs would be the objective function `f` and permutation length `n`, with underlying assumption that `f` works with permutations of `Range[n]`. Plus any other inputs you might want (temperatiure function, quenching rate, whatever).

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @DanielLichtblau . It works, yes; and yet right now my construction feels a bit amateurish to me, because I have no intuition for the topology of the space of permutations and how one travels efficiently in this space (maybe with steps that aren't 2-cycles?). I'll be thinking and researching some more.

Comment: Upon a bit more reflection it seems that it takes only $M-1$ applications of a 2-cycle (a permutation of two indices) to go from any permutation of length $M$ to any other. So the method proposed above may not be bad after all, as it can cross permutation space rather quickly despite the space's incredible vastness.

Comment: Thanks Roman. You can very easily apply n-cycles with: `randomperm[L_,n_] := Permute[L, Cycles[{RandomSample[Range[Length@L], n]}]]`, and then I'm trying drawing the $n$ from a negative binomial distribution, so it weights to small shuffles but sometimes tries large ones.

Comment: @KraZug any success with random n-cycles? I'm still wondering if they are more trouble than they're worth. I'd be interested in your experience, and could update the code if it's an improvement.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I've added a cleaned-up version of the code to this site. What would be the advantage of placing it in the WFR?

Comment: @Roman, I suspect it depends on the underlying structure of the objective function. I've found this gets stuck in a local minima and didn't get out. 
My actual objective function is finding words in a string of scrabble tiles (without blanks - https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/whats-your-best-scrabble-string/), which it ends up with strings that are definitely still suboptimal.

Comment: @KraZug you may get better results by using a slow anneal and starting with a pretty small $\beta$, in this way you're less likely to get stuck in local optima.

Comment: @Roman, yes. I added the code for the objective function into my post, in case you want to try it. My best so far with the MH algorithm is 968. It is possible I just need to run it for longer with more reps (and potentially the slowly increasing beta).

Comment: The advantage, as I see it, is that we really do not have any dedicated permutation optimization functionality. We may add some, and there are of course ways to adapt/co-opt/trick `NMinimize` into performing some amount of such heuristic optimization. But what you present seems to work quite efficiently, and reasonably well, and if it goes into the WFR I suspect it might see a fair amount of usage.

Comment: @KraZug Just half an hour of MH iterations gets me to `getScore=1200` for your Scrabble problem: try `{70, 31, 8, 48, 50, 66, 93, 24, 14, 34, 38, 25, 78, 81, 73, 9, 96, 19, 15, 89, 44, 85, 61, 97, 63, 69, 43, 58, 32, 65, 71, 28, 53, 67, 91, 18, 17, 46, 42, 55, 54, 40, 49, 10, 76, 1, 33, 7, 52, 4, 77, 35, 3, 92, 21, 75, 80, 29, 84, 87, 56, 41, 12, 5, 68, 26, 72, 83, 90, 82, 88, 11, 2, 98, 60, 64, 57, 20, 30, 51, 37, 13, 36, 39, 16, 27, 74, 23, 94, 62, 47, 22, 59, 86, 6, 95, 45, 79}`.

Comment: The other advantage is that you can give WFR functions the type of documentation found in regular WL functions. That would include, if so desired, Applications and Neat Examples.

Comment: I used your annealing variant on the NUG25 problem that has been in benchmarks for a few decades (I show it in the tutorial notes I pointed to in a comment). Here's the thing. Your method found a global optimum* within 10^5 steps (less than half a minute). Asterisk: It won't find the global every time for that number of steps. But it will come close. This is quite powerful. I'd really like to see this in the WFR (and maybe some day in the Wolfram Language proper).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau wow that's good to know, thanks for checking. I'm working on making the code nicer, more general, and full of warning and error messages, in preparation for a WFR upload. Will let you know. Is there a code review option for WFR?

Comment: We will review the submission. If you have particular requests or remarks to address to the reviewers, there is a Submission Notes section at the bottom that is intended exactly for this purpose. One recommendation is that you show NUG25 and/or NUG30 in the examples. I just did a 38 second run at NUG30 and got a result of 6136, where the global min is 6124. I was surprised to do get that close that quickly. The input matrices (and many other benchmarks) can be found [here](http://anjos.mgi.polymtl.ca/qaplib/inst.html)

Comment: Also: I modified the probability of acceptance to not use `N[`]`, and changed the exponential to use a bignum numeric evaluation a la N[...,20]` in order to work around exponent underflows. Probably makes no difference, but still...

Comment: Addendum: Possibly a lucky run, but I hit the global min for NUG30 using 10^6 iterations with the temperature change version. Also I did not memoize since that can blow up memory usage. But really that's an issue for the user, in creating the objective function.

Comment: Check this: https://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/phd-thesis-solving-large-scale-quadratic-assignment-problems/ The gist is that NUG30 took 7 days on a massively parallelized computation back in 2000. One difference is that they used a method that delivers the provable global optimum.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Even so, 7 days seems like an amazing feat, considering there are 30! permutations to check. Thanks for the info. I'll be happy to WFR-submit this code once it's cleaned up and documented, so that others can play with it.

Comment: Thanks for the bonus, @DanielLichtblau ! I've submitted the code to WFR and can send you a copy if you point me to the right channel (LinkedIn, for example).

Comment: No need, I'm on the review team and I see it's arrived in the queue. We prioritize reviews for new contributors so we'll likely look at it in the review meeting later today. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: I guess I woke up today dumb as an ox. I cannot get the resource function to work if I give `Method->"MonteCarlo"`. And when I fill in some suboptions as is in the WFR shingle it still balks. I used `Method \[RightArrow] {"MonteCarlo", "Iterations" -> 10000, 
  "AnnealingParameter" -> 1, "StartingPermutation" -> Automatic}`. I get the message `Method must be either "Enumerate" or {"MonteCarlo",...}`. If you have a bit of time please send me a note (first 3 letters of first name + last letter of first name@w.c)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau use `->` or `\[Rule]` instead of `\[RightArrow]`, cheers!

Comment: Thanks Roman. That was just painful. I never actually entered `\[RightArrow]` so there must have been an autoconversion somewhere that I did not see. Anyway, it works better now. One suggestion: Add an `Automatic` default that switches from enumeration to Monte Carlo at some threshold, as 12 or so.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This is the second time within a couple of weeks that I see someone mistake a `\[RightArrow]` for a `\[Rule]`; previously I had never heard of this confusion. Maybe something in the copy/paste Unicode interface between the operating system and the Mathematica front end has changed recently? Please give a heads-up to the Front End department.

Comment: I was intending to do exactly that. Will notify them today. Thanks again Roman.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach from among the ones I allude to in a comment.

```
f[samp_?ListQ] := 
 Total@Total@
   Table[Table[(-1)^(i), {i, 1, Length[samp]}]*
     Reverse@Cos[Mod[samp, n]]*
     Mod[samp, n], {n, {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23}}]
```

Now just define a function that takes a numeric vector, creates a permutation, and evaluates `f` on it.

```
g[ll : {_?NumberQ ..}] := N[f[Ordering[ll]]]
```

We can get a reasonable value with `NMaximize`. Restricting the range of the values seems to help here.

```
n = 100;
vars = Array[x, n];
AbsoluteTiming[{max, vals} = 
   NMaximize[{g[vars], Thread[0 <= vars <= 1]}, 
    Map[{#, 0, 1} &, vars], MaxIterations -> 5000];]
max
best = Ordering[vars /. vals]
N[f[best]]

(* During evaluation of In[140]:= NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 5000 iterations.

Out[142]= {62.699518, Null}

Out[143]= 636.619153268

Out[144]= {9, 40, 46, 2, 19, 47, 53, 77, 97, 87, 21, 33, 71, 35, 95, \
73, 39, 28, 52, 43, 6, 75, 5, 20, 27, 31, 22, 64, 49, 83, 42, 38, 92, \
58, 65, 79, 30, 11, 12, 13, 7, 66, 86, 67, 41, 4, 72, 100, 60, 10, 1, \
48, 81, 8, 84, 55, 36, 32, 25, 96, 70, 44, 80, 16, 18, 68, 29, 88, \
89, 15, 91, 69, 23, 17, 82, 90, 94, 93, 50, 99, 59, 85, 74, 62, 56, \
26, 24, 34, 78, 3, 98, 63, 14, 61, 51, 76, 45, 54, 37, 57}

Out[145]= 636.619153268 *)
```

Could of course instead minimize in the same manner. Also there are numerous variations one might try, using option and method sub-option settings for `NMinimize`.

Comment: Ahh, that is such a simple way to turn the permutation problem into something that the built-in functions can work on.

Answer (score 3):

it seems that Objective Function must return Numeric Value,not Symbolic expression.

```
f[samp_?ListQ] := 
 Total@Total@
   Table[Table[(-1)^(i), {i, 1, Length[samp]}]*
     Reverse@Cos[Mod[samp, n]]*
     Mod[samp, n], {n, {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23}}]

Nf[samp_?ListQ] := 
 N@Total@Total@
    Table[Table[(-1)^(i), {i, 1, Length[samp]}]*
      Reverse@Cos[Mod[samp, n]]*
      Mod[samp, n], {n, {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23}}]
```

```
Print[forwardDP[f, Range[1, 100]] // f // N]
```

> -118.075

```
Print[forwardDP[Nf, Range[1, 100]] // Nf]
```

> 1164.08

---

The first thing that came to mind is the heuristic.
The other is approximated dynamic programming.

#### *Heuristic*

Easy and Fast Heuristic Implementation.

```
Table[
   Nest[
    With[{try = RandomSample@Range[100]},
        tryvalue = f[try];
        If[#2 >= tryvalue, {#1, #2},
         {try, tryvalue}]] & @@ # &,
    {1, -10000}, 500],
   {100}
   ] // MaximalBy[#, #[[2]] &] & // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*no elements should be duplicate.*)
Not@*Equal @@ # & /@ Subsets[First@%, {2}] // And @@ # &
```

=>

> True

#### *Dynamic Programming(forward)*

```
forwardDP[obj_, action_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &)] := 
  Block[{solution, nothing, tryaction}, 
   solution = ConstantArray[nothing, Length@action];
   Do[solution[[index]] = First[First[Table[solution[[index]] = trynum;
         tryaction = 
          Join[DeleteCases[solution, nothing], 
           DeleteCases[action, x_ /; ContainsAny[solution][{x}]]];
         {trynum, obj[tryaction]}, {trynum, 
          DeleteCases[action, 
           x_ /; ContainsAny[DeleteCases[solution, nothing]][{x}]]}] //
         MaximalBy[#, #[[2]] &] &]], {index, Range[1, Length@action]}];
   solution];


forwardDP[f, Range[1, 100]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[%]
```

=>

> ```
> 608
> ```

```
Not@*Equal @@ # & /@ Subsets[%%, {2}] // And @@ # &
```

=>

> True

About feasible region of control/action,please modify the code around `DeleteCases` of `trynum` and `tryaction` for your problem.

Comment: Can you explain what the dynamic programming code is doing?

Comment: for each time-step,from `index=1 to index=100`,We tried *all possible solution from feasible region determined by the constraints* and take the best one.

Comment: First re-write the solution for that time step,`index` with `trynum`, then create a candidate solution`tryaction` that satisfies the constraints.

Comment: please note when we choose the best action,sometime `MaximalBy` returns more than two values whose scores are the same depending on the object function. in that case tweak the constraint.

Comment: Finally,this is *approximated* dynamic programming,there may be better optimal solution,but this is efficiency more than heuristic or NMaximize: )

Comment: Ok, so the `forwardDP` function tries varying the first component by shuffling each number in turn to the front and pushing the others down. This works nicely for the initial function that I gave, because each component was independent of the others. For a nonlocal function $f$ it does a lot less well.

Comment: Could you check the update?

Answer (score 0):

Code to include the blank tiles:

Revised 7/26/19: (previous code did not include definition of cRange--added it).  Also converted the addition of the two blank tiles to a function.

We have 98 lettered tiles and two blanks.  We first compile a list of all possible combinations of 2-letters for the blanks.  Run metropolis with M=100 for each combination.  That gives 351 runs.  Find the maximum from that set.  Here is the code to incorporate the blanks in the list:

```
    cRange = CharacterRange["a", "z"]
theBlanks = 
  Join[Subsets[CharacterRange["a", "z"], {2}], {#, #} & /@ cRange];

scrabbleList[n_] := 
 "eeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaiiiiiiiiioooooooonnnnnnrrrrrrttttttllllssssuuuu\
ddddgggbbccmmppffhhvvwwyykjxqz" <> theBlanks[[n]]
```

Note:  See [Solution to scrabble puzzle](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/whats-the-optimal-way-to-play-horse/) for a 1629 score using the letter "S" twice.

Comment: Was this intended as a response to a different question?

Comment: No.  Just found the problem interesting.  Please delete if off-topic.

Comment: I gather now that this is also intended to be a permutation optimization problem.  Probably it should be a separate thread (linking to this one). But maybe the moderators will be okay with having it here. It does need a full specification however. I do not know what `cRange` is, or what specifically is to be optimized, so Mathematica code for the objective function would need to be added.

Comment: Hi Daniel,  the OP stated the problem: https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/whats-your-best-scrabble-string/.  Essentially find the combination of 100 scrabble letters with the most points (2 blanks included).   Roman above basically wrote the code to do the problem with the 98 pieces and I was just interested in how it would be done with the two blank pieced added.  If I had time I would work it through.  Maybe sometime in the future.  It's a beautiful problem I think.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, yes, I updated my question explaining that was my actual objective function. Thank you for giving the bounty btw, Roman's answer definitely deserves it. I have considered making that a separate question.

Comment: Dominic and KraZug, thank you both for your clarifications. It's clear now.