# How to use genetic algorithm to calculate the maximum value of this matrix

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

1-9 the 9 numbers are arranged into 3 * 3 matrix without repetition.How to select the matrix with the largest determinant value:

```
list = Permutations[Range[9], {9}];
matrix = Partition[#, 3] & /@ list;
answer = Det /@ matrix;
m = Max[answer];
pos = Flatten[Position[answer, m]];
matrix[[#]] & /@ pos
Det[%[[1]]]
```

I've used permutation to get results, but how can I use genetic algorithms to achieve similar results.

Comment: Why not try NMaximum with Method->”DifferentialEvolution”

Comment: see also [this answer by Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201423/125)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follows a classical Genetic Algorithm with the normal functionalities as

1. Population initialization
2. Fitness Evaluation
3. Crossover
4. Mutation
5. Offspring Selection

The main difficulty found to implement this procedure was the crossover implementation, because the offspring should preserve always the same elements (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) without absences or repetitions. By this reason, the corrections needed after the one-point crossover, are considered as mutations. The program bulk was extracted from one repository but were included the essential modifications. The script can be utilized for a generic matrix dimension **dim**.

```
Clear[doMutation];
doMutation[string_] := Module[{tempstring, i, ind1, ind2, atom}, tempstring = string;
If[Random[] < mutationRate,
ind1 = RandomInteger[{1, length}];
ind2 = RandomInteger[{1, length}];
atom = tempstring[[ind1]];
tempstring[[ind1]] = tempstring[[ind2]];
tempstring[[ind2]] = atom];
Return[tempstring]]

Clear[correct]
correct[lista_] := Module[{out, ok = Table[0, length],
list = lista, i, k, ind},
out = Complement[Range[length], list];
If[Length[out] == 0, Return[list], 
For[i = 1; k = 1, i <= length, i++, ind = list[[i]]; 
If[ok[[ind]] == 0, ok[[ind]] = 1, list[[i]] = out[[k]]; k = k + 1]]];
Return[list]]

Clear[fitnessFunction];
fitnessFunction[list_] := Max[0, Det[ArrayReshape[list, {dim, dim}]]]

Clear[doSingleCrossover];
doSingleCrossover[ string1_, string2_] := Module[{cut, temp1, temp2},
cut = RandomInteger[{1, length}];
temp1 = Join[ Take[string1, cut], Drop[string2, cut] ];
temp2 = Join[ Take[string2, cut], Drop[string1, cut] ];
{correct[temp1], correct[temp2]} ]

Clear[doCumSumOfFitness];
doCumSumOfFitness := Module[{temp},
temp = 0.0;
Table[ temp += popFitness[[i]], {i, popSize} ]]

Clear[doSingleSelection];
doSingleSelection := Module[{rfitness, ind},
rfitness = RandomReal[{0, cumFitness[[popSize]]}];
ind = 1;
While[ rfitness > cumFitness[[ind]], ind++ ];
Return[ind]]

Clear[selectPair];
selectPair := Module[{ind1, ind2},
ind1 = doSingleSelection;
While[ (ind2 = doSingleSelection) == ind1 ];
{ind1, ind2}]

Clear[pickRandomPair];
pickRandomPair := Module[{ind1, ind2},
ind1 = RandomInteger[{1, popSize}];
While[ (ind2 = RandomInteger[ {1, popSize}]) == ind1 ];
{ind1, ind2}]

Clear[exchangeString];
exchangeString[ind_, newstring_, newF_] := Module[{},
popStrings[[ind]] = newstring;
popFitness[[ind]] = newF]

Clear[renormalizeFitness];
renormalizeFitness[fitness0_List] := Module[{minF, maxF, a, b, fitness = fitness0, i},
minF = Min[fitness];
maxF = Max[fitness];
a = 0.5*maxF/(maxF + minF);
b = (1 - a)*maxF;
Map[  a # + b &, fitness]]

Clear[bestDet]
bestDet := Module[{bestFitness = -1, i, ibest = 1},
For[i = 1, i <= popSize, i++, 
If[popFitness[[i]] > bestFitness, bestFitness = popFitness[[i]]; ibest = i]];
If[bestFitness > bestOfAll, bestOfAll = bestFitness; 
bestIndividual = popStrings[[ibest]]];
Return[popStrings[[ibest]]]]

Clear[doInitialize];
doInitialize := Module[{i},
popFitness = Table[fitnessFunction[popStrings[[i]]], {i, popSize} ];
popFitness = renormalizeFitness[popFitness];
cumFitness = doCumSumOfFitness;
listOfCumFitness = {cumFitness[[popSize]]};
historyOfPop = {bestDet}]

Clear[updateGenerationSync];
updateGenerationSync := Module[{parentsid, children, ip},
parentsid = {};
Do[AppendTo[parentsid, selectPair], {popSize/2}];
children = {};
Do[AppendTo[children, 
doSingleCrossover[popStrings[[parentsid[[ip, 1]]]], 
popStrings[[parentsid[[ip, 2]]]]]], {ip, popSize/2}];
popStrings = Flatten[ children, 1];
popStrings = Map[doMutation, popStrings];
popFitness = Map[fitnessFunction, popStrings];
popFitness = renormalizeFitness[popFitness];
cumFitness = doCumSumOfFitness]
```

And now the main program

```
SeedRandom[4];
bestOfAll = -1;
dim = 6;
length = dim^2;
popSize = 100; (* should be even *)
numberOfEpochs = 500;
mutationRate = 0.005;
popStrings = Table[RandomSample[Range[length], length], {popSize} ];
doInitialize;

Do[updateGenerationSync;
AppendTo[historyOfPop,bestDet];
AppendTo[ listOfCumFitness, cumFitness[[popSize]] ],
{numberOfEpochs} ];

ListLinePlot[listOfCumFitness, PlotRange -> All ]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Map[fitnessFunction, historyOfPop], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
bestIndividual
fitnessFunction[bestIndividual]

(*{27, 11, 36, 29, 6, 14, 23, 16, 22, 4, 34, 10, 18, 33, 1, 32, 13, 8, 31, 3, 2, 9, 12, 25, 5, 7, 20, 26, 19, 28, 21, 35, 24, 17, 15, 30}*)

(*1181916347*)
```

NOTE

This script can be enhanced including elitism.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can you modify this algorithm to quickly find the maximal determinant in the case of  6×6 matrix using the integers 1 to 36 quickly ?
http://oeis.org/search?q=10%2C412%2C40800%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: The script now is general for any dimension **dim**

Answer (score 5):

Using the function `MaximizeOverPermutations` from [this great answer by Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201423/125):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[samp_List] := Det[Partition[samp, 3]]
MaximizeOverPermutations[f, 9, {1/100, 10}, 10^4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.664876, {{5,7,1,3,6,8,9,2,4}, 412.}}

```
ResourceFunction["MaximizeOverPermutations"][f, 9]
```

> {{{1, 4, 8, 7, 2, 6, 5, 9, 3}, {1, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6, 4, 9, 2}, {1, 7, 5, 
>      4, 2, 9, 8, 6, 3}, {1, 8, 4, 5, 3, 9, 7, 6, 2}, {2, 4, 9, 7, 1, 5, 
>      6, 8, 3}, {2, 6, 7, 9, 3, 5, 4, 8, 1}, {2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 8, 9, 5, 
>      3}, {2, 9, 4, 6, 3, 8, 7, 5, 1}, {3, 5, 9, 8, 1, 4, 6, 7, 2}, {3, 
>      6, 8, 9, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1}, {3, 8, 6, 5, 1, 7, 9, 4, 2}, {3, 9, 5, 6, 
>      2, 7, 8, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 7, 6}, {4, 2, 9, 8, 6, 3, 1, 
>      7, 5}, {4, 8, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3, 5}, {4, 9, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 3, 
>      6}, {5, 1, 7, 9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 6}, {5, 3, 9, 7, 6, 2, 1, 8, 4}, {5, 
>      7, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 2, 4}, {5, 9, 3, 1, 4, 8, 7, 2, 6}, {6, 2, 7, 8, 
>      4, 1, 3, 9, 5}, {6, 3, 8, 7, 5, 1, 2, 9, 4}, {6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 9, 8, 
>      1, 4}, {6, 8, 3, 2, 4, 9, 7, 1, 5}, {7, 1, 5, 6, 8, 3, 2, 4, 
>      9}, {7, 2, 6, 5, 9, 3, 1, 4, 8}, {7, 5, 1, 2, 9, 4, 6, 3, 8}, {7, 
>      6, 2, 1, 8, 4, 5, 3, 9}, {8, 1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 9}, {8, 3, 6, 4, 
>      9, 2, 1, 5, 7}, {8, 4, 1, 3, 9, 5, 6, 2, 7}, {8, 6, 3, 1, 7, 5, 4, 
>      2, 9}, {9, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 3, 6, 8}, {9, 3, 5, 4, 8, 1, 2, 6, 
>      7}, {9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 6, 5, 1, 7}, {9, 5, 3, 2, 7, 6, 4, 1, 8}}, 412}

For 4X4 matrices:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[samp_List] := Det[Partition[samp, 4]]

MaximizeOverPermutations[f2, 16, {1/100, 10}, 10^4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.0341155, {{11, 4, 5, 15, 1, 9, 14, 10, 8, 16, 3, 7, 13, 6, 12, 2}, 
>         40800.}}

and 5X5:

```
ClearAll[f3]
f3[samp_List] := Det[Partition[samp, 5]]

MaximizeOverPermutations[f3, 25, {1/100, 10}, 10^4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.3268, {{1, 8, 17, 20, 19, 15, 13, 24, 11, 2, 22, 4, 12, 6, 21, 9, 
>          25, 10, 5, 16, 18, 14, 3, 23, 7}, 6.83813*^6}}

Comment: MOP is a wonderful function. Note that at its core it is simulated annealing and not a genetic method. (Presumably the original poster really wants for any working method, not necessarily one from the evolutionary algorithms family.)

Comment: This yields `6.838.13* `  for n==5. But `http://oeis.org/search?q=10%2C412%2C40800%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search` gives `6.839.492` as maximum for n==5. What is true?

Comment: @Akku14,  I think changing `10^4` in the 4th argument to a larger number we can get closer to the OEIS number.

Comment: Very nice! Glad to see my code is finding usage.

Comment: You can save some time by defining `f[samp_List] := Det[Partition[samp, n] // N]`: for some reason the floating-point algorithm is faster than the integer algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Maximize works for 2*2 matrix, but gets out of memory for 3*3 on my 16 GB computer.

```
max4 = Maximize[{Det@Partition[Array[a, 4], 2], 
   And @@ Thread[0 < Array[a, 4] < 5] && 
   Unequal @@ Array[a, 4]}, 
      Array[a, 4], Integers]

(* {10, {a[1] -> 3, a[2] -> 1, a[3] -> 2, a[4] -> 4}} *)

nmax9 = Maximize[{Det@Partition[Array[a, 9], 3], 
   And @@ Thread[0 < Array[a, 9] < 10] && 
   Unequal @@ Array[a, 9]}, 
       Array[a, 9], Integers]

(*   No more memory available.
     Mathematica kernel has shut down.   *)
```

**Edit**

NMaximize with method "SimulatedAnnealing" gives you at least one of the 36 solutions within one minute.

```
nmax9 = NMaximize[{Det@Partition[Array[a, 9], 3], 
  And @@ Thread[0 < Array[a, 9] < 10] && Unequal @@ Array[a, 9] && 
  Element[Array[a, 9], Integers]}, Array[a, 9], 
  MaxIterations -> 10000, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]

(*   {412., {a[1] -> 1, a[2] -> 8, a[3] -> 4, 
a[4] -> 5, a[5] -> 3, a[6] -> 9, a[7] -> 7, a[8] -> 6, a[9] -> 2}}   *)
```

Method `"DifferentialEvolution"` finds an other of the 36 solutions.

```
(*   {412., {a[1] -> 3, a[2] -> 8, a[3] -> 6, a[4] -> 5, a[5] -> 1, 
a[6] -> 7, a[7] -> 9, a[8] -> 4, a[9] -> 2}}*)
```

Comment: i don't get it: how can the kernel run out of memory if the total population is fixed in a genetic algorithm? from what i know the new generation take the place of the lower ranked members of the previous generation

Comment: I must confess, I don't know, what exactly a "genetic" algorithm is. I copied it from the OP.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-including-example-code-e396e98d8bf3
i am a newbie too, i googled it  because it sounds interesting

Comment: @Alucard There is a simple genetic algorithm code in the following answer.

Comment: @alucarD It was `Maximize` that ran out of memory, not `NMaximize`. The former uses exact methods, in this case either involving Lagrange multipliers and exact polynomial system solving, or else some form of cylindric decomposition. Both can be explosively consumptive of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

A "genetic algorithm" of this question:

```
(*QQ:2636051698*)
maxDet[n_, size_, iterations_] := 
  Module[{fitness, choose, mutation, mutationInGroup, result}, 
   fitness = 
    Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, 
     Evaluate@Det@Quiet@Array[list[[n # + #2 - n]] &, {n, n}], 
     RuntimeAttributes -> Listable];
   choose[group_] := group[[Ordering[Abs@fitness@group, -size]]];
   mutation = 
    Compile[{{gene, _Real, 1}}, 
     Module[{list = gene, changePos = RandomSample[Range[n^2], 3]}, 
      list[[changePos]] = RandomSample[list[[changePos]]];
      list], RuntimeAttributes -> Listable];
   mutationInGroup[group_] := group~Join~(mutation /@ group);
   result = 
    Nest[choose@mutationInGroup@# &, 
      Table[RandomSample[Range[n^2]], {i, 1, 10^5}], iterations][[1]];
   {MatrixForm[Partition[result, n]], Round@fitness@result}];
maxDet[4, 100, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code failes for n >= 5 on my MMA Version 8.0. Maximia are { 1, 10, 412, 40800, 6839492, 1865999570, 762150368499}  according to `http://oeis.org/search?q=10%2C412%2C40800%2C&sort=&language=english&go=Search` .

Comment: @Akku14 This needs to wait for the others of the SE community to revise and speed up or open a new post tomorrow.

Comment: @Akku14 Someone has used genetic algorithm to answer this question.