# Find Max Instance Over Permutations

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, permutation

I would like to find the maximum of some objective function over all possible permutations

```
(* Memory inefficient solution *)
Max[obj/@Permutations[lst]]

(* Outout: SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] *)
```

While this computation might be intractably slow $O(n!)$, it should have $O(n)$ space for `lst` of size $n$.

Is there an efficient way to only cache the max seen so far? Thanks

Here is a standalone trivial example for the purposes of testing

````
n = 10;
l = Range[n];

Max[l . # & /@ Permutations[l]]
(* 385 *)
```
````

Comment: There is the aptly named [ResourceFunction`["MaximizeOverPermutations"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaximizeOverPermutations)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201333/optimization-of-function-taking-a-permutation/201423#201423

Comment: Is "The number of permutations of n objects scales very quickly with n. The default "Enumerate" method should not be used with n≳12 in order to prevent memory overflow" from the Possible Issues a concern since the OP asks for O(n) in space?  I suppose the linked question may answer this since it is ostensibly the source code for the function.