# Map Inverse Ordering on Matrix

Tags: matrix, map, order

I have an matrix (symmetric, but any $n \times n$ will do)

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4.5 & 6 & 5.5 \\ 
4.5 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
6 & 4 & 0 & 5 \\ 
5.5 & 3 & 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to replace this matrix on matrix with ranks in each row (ascending), ex:
$$A^* = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 
3 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
3 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

In Wolfram Mathematica I tried this way with mapping `Ordering`:

```
ranked = Ordering /@ Ordering /@ A - 1;
ranked

Out[1]: {{0,1,3,2},{3,0,2,1},{3,1,0,2},{3,1,2,0}}
```

Is there a way to do it simpler? Without mapping two times ordering function.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: "but it doesn't make sense" doesn't make sense to me.  Explain.

Comment: I mean, that it doesn't matter what kind of matrix is, in my example it is symmetric, but it should work on every input matrix.

Comment: "doesn't matter", sorry for mistake

Comment: related: [ls `Ordering[Ordering[list]]` optimal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194094/125)