# Fail to understand Ordering[], need to get the ranking of elements in a list

Tags: sorting

Ordering[{2, 1, 6, 4, 7, 10}]

gives me as a result, {2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6}, which I understand, 10 is the 6th smallest element. However

```
Ordering[{2, 1, 6, 4, 7, 10, -1}]
```

or

```
Ordering[{56, 120, 80, 192, 21, 42, 20, 36}]
```

utterly confuses me.
DO I missunderstand the Command and the help?
I want

```
Command[{1,4,-1}]
```

gives me the result {2,1,3} and not {3, 1, 2} as Ordering[] does

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you misunderstanding. `Ordering` gives the indices of the least element, second-to-least element, etc. So `Ordering[{1, 4, -1}]` should (and does) return `{3, 1, 2}` because the third element of `{1, 4, -1}` is the smallest, the first element is the second-smallest, and the second element is the largest.  How does that not make sense, especially since you're fine with `Ordering[{2, 1, 6, 4, 7, 10}]` being `{2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6}`? Perhaps you want them ordered in the reverse order? Then do `Reverse@Ordering[list]`.

Comment: @march I believe OP wants `Ordering@Ordering[list]`.

Comment: You say you want {3, 1, 2} as the output.  Are you sure you didn't mean {2, 3, 1}, meaning that 1 is the 2nd smallest, 4 is the 3rd smallest, -1 is the smallest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ls Ordering\[Ordering\[list\]\] optimal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194094/ls-orderingorderinglist-optimal)

Comment: @Roman I don't that's a fair duplicate. Your question assumes that the reader already has a good understanding of the issues I discuss in my answer. I think these things are sufficiently confusing that they merit their own answer. For example, I'm wondering how many people reading this were aware of the difference between `Permute[list, x]` and `list[[x]]`.  It is however a very good followup reading, so I'll include a link in my answer.

Comment: For an old MathGroup post on `ordering@ordering`, see [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00931.html). And (from there) `(Sort@mylist)[[Ordering@Ordering@mylist]] == mylist`

Comment: Dear all, I actually really misunderstood Ordering and therefore also didn't get Ordering@Ordering I found in another thread! 
THANKS alot for the super fast answers

Answer (score 12):

**tl;dr** You are looking for "ranks", i.e. indices into the sorted version of the list. `Ordering` yields indices into the original (unsorted) version of the list. You need to "invert" these to obtain the ranks.

You can use the command `Ordering@Ordering[list]`.

#### Clearing up the confusion

`Ordering[originalList]` gives a list of integer indices `p` so that `sortedList = originalList[[p]]` yields the elements of `originalList` in sorted order. `p` contains indices into `originalList`. These are not ranks.

The "ranks" you talk about when you say that "10 is the 6th smallest element" are *not* indices into `originalList`, but indices into `sortedList`.

The simplest way to obtain the ranks you are looking for is to use `r = Ordering[p]`. The elements of `r` are now indices into `sortedList`, meaning that `sortedList[[r]]` yields `originalList`. If we think of `p` as a permutation, then applying `Ordering` to it effectively inverts it. If you try this, you will notice that *with your specific example* `r == p`, which may have contributed to your confusion. So let's take a different and less confusing example:

```
originalList = {b, c, e, a, d};

p = Ordering[originalList]
(* {4, 1, 2, 5, 3} *)
```

This result tells us that the "smallest" element (i.e. `a`) is currently in the 4th place, the second smallest (i.e. `b`) is in the 1st place, the third smallest is currently in the 2nd place, etc.

```
sortedList = originalList[[p]]
(* {a, b, c, d, e} *)
```

Now let's compute the ranks:

```
r = Ordering[p]
(* {2, 3, 5, 1, 4} *)
```

This is what you were looking for. The first element of `originalList` must move to the 2nd place, the second to 3rd place, the third to 5th place, etc. to obtain `sortedList`.

Notice that the following yields `originalList`:

```
sortedList[[r]]
(* {b, c, e, a, d} *)

sortedList[[r]] === originalList
(* True *)
```

Also notice that `r` and `p` are each other's inverse permutations:

```
r[[p]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

p[[r]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

#### About the representation of permutations

It's good to point out that if we wanted to represent permutations, then *either* `p` *or* `r` would be a valid representation for the permutation that sorts `originalList`. Which representation we choose is a matter of convention. When you read about ["permutations"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Permutations.html) in the Mathematica documentation, it is actually the second representation (i.e. `r`) that is used. So if we want to sort `originalList` using the [`Permute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) function (instead of [the `[[ ... ]]` indexing operator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)), then we must use `r`:

```
Permute[originalList, r]
(* {a, b, c, d, e} *)
```

The second argument of [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) also uses the same representation as `Permute` for permuting "levels" of a multidimensional array. Physicists might think of this as permuting tensor indices.

#### How to invert a permutation?

My final note is that in a procedural language you would probably compute `r` from `p` along these lines:

```
result = ConstantArray[0, Length[p]];
result[[p]] = Range@Length[p];
result

(* {2, 3, 5, 1, 4} *)
```

This will probably be more intuitive for most people, but it's a bit long to write in Mathematica. This is why my go-to approach is `r = Ordering[p]`.

Be aware that the more complex procedural approach will be more efficient (linear time) than a second application of `Ordering` (which does a sort, so probably $O(n \log n)$). See this question for a discussion of performance issues:

- [ls Ordering[Ordering[list]] optimal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194094/12)

Comment: There's also `InversePermutation` which one could use in place of the second `Ordering` call (which might be a bit more expressive for some people)

Comment: @LukasLang Indeed, and that is mentioned in the QA I linked to at the end. The reason I didn't include it is that all permutation handling functions can operate on both list and cycles representations. The documentation does not give a guarantee about which representation they will return. Most functions appear to prefer returning a cycles representation. `InversePermutation` appears to return the same representation that was input. But is this perhaps only because it's easier/faster to do it this way? (It's certainly algorithmically easier.) Are there guarantees for it?

Comment: Good point about the different representations, I haven't considered that... As noted in the comments in the linked Q&A, you can apply `PermutationList` to the result to force a given representation, but now it becomes a bit lengthy...

Comment: Dear @Szabolcs, I actually really misunderstood Ordering and therefore also didn't get Ordering@Ordering I found in another thread! 
THANKS alot for this long and helpful answer